# Changing li class on horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I want to know if it's possible to change my "selected" `li` class based on the movements of the horizontal scroll. So when you start moving the scroll to the right, the selected `li` class would change to 2, 3, 4 .. and so on.

Any hints or points to start from are appreciated.

My code:

```
<div id="scroller">
<ul id="ulscroller">
<li value="1" class="selected">1</li>
<li value="2">2</li>
<li value="3">3</li>
<li value="4">4</li>
<li value="5">5</li>
<li value="6">6</li>
<li value="7">7</li>
<li value="8">8</li>
<li value="9">9</li>
<li value="10">10</li>
<li value="11">11</li>
<li value="12">12</li>
<li value="13">13</li>
<li value="14">14</li>
<li value="15">15</li>
<li value="16">16</li>
<li value="17">17</li>
<li value="18">18</li>
<li value="19">19</li>
<li value="20">20</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
li {float:left; padding:10px; cursor: pointer;}
    div#scroller {width:300px; height:70px; overflow-x: scroll;}
    ul#ulscroller {list-style: none outside none; margin: 0;
        padding: 0; width:655px;}
    ul#ulscroller li.selected {border:1px solid #000;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uCS8/

Comment: Yes it is possible using onscroll. What is the parameter that would decide what li would be picked? When it hits the edge?

Comment: while the user scrolls horizontally, so i think When it hits the edge of the next number would be good.

Comment: And what happens when it hits the point where there is no more room to scroll? 13-20 would not be selected.

Comment: after 20, it should display 1,2,3,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea:

```
var scroller = document.getElementById("scroller"),
    lis = scroller.getElementsByTagName("li"),
    divisionsWidth = lis[0].offsetWidth - 2,
    current = 0,
scroller.onscroll = function(){
    var selected = Math.floor(scroller.scrollLeft/divisionsWidth);
    if (current!==selected) {
        lis[current].className="";
        lis[selected].className="selected";
        current = selected;
    }
};
```

It can be tweaked to change the selection, but it should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe, since the li's have a defined width you can get the current scroll in pixels with each scrolling event (easily done with jQuery) and if the scroll position is within any position to change the class name, change it. I'd rather use an id value for each li element to identify it easily with JavaScript and a class for group removing the class. Something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (scrollPosition >= 0 && scrollPosition < 300) {
        $("li.scroller_children").removeClass("selected");
        $("li#1").addClass("selected");
    } elseif (scrollPosition >= 300 && scrollPosition < 900) {
        $("li.scroller_children").removeClass("selected");
        $("li#2").addClass("selected");
    } elseif ....
});
```

I

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do something like this.

```
$(window).scroll(function (scrolledTo) {
    $("li:[value=" + scrolledTo).addClass("selected");
    $("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
});
```

Unfortunately I do not know how to get where the window was scrolled to (`scrolledTo`) from the event and it doesn't appear to be in the jQuery documentation. However, you said you wanted a starting point, so I thought this would at least provide you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, need some modifications...

```
$("#scroller").scroll(function () { 
     $(".selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");
});
```